# How limit the  number of results of a database query?

Tags: php, sql, oscommerce

**I want to display the number of products on home page**.

My code is:

```
$categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.categories_image, c.parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.parent_id = '" . (int)$category_links[$i] . "' and c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' order by sort_order, cd.categories_name");
```

I want to set a limit of only 6 products (for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a LIMIT argument to the end of your statement..

```
$categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.categories_image, c.parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.parent_id = '" . (int)$category_links[$i] . "' and c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "' order by sort_order, cd.categories_name LIMIT 6");
```

Comment: At least that's if I'm understanding your question properly

Comment: thanks a lot dear can you tell me how can change these products when we refresh our page using rand() functio aur other one thanks

Comment: just change your ORDER to be RAND(c.categories_id), sort_order, cd.categories_name

You could substitute c.categories_id for which ever random value you want.

Comment: thanks a lot dear just help me a little bit more i want to change image when we refersh the page for this i used ("' order by rand(p.products_date_added)  desc  limit 0,6")